# How can I pipe to the next command with new environment variables?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a shell script that declares some variables:

```
export X=1
export Y=2
```

and I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
. ./path/to/script | command_that_has_access_to_X_and_Y
```

Basically, source the script somehow, so that the command following the pipe could access those variables. Is such a thing possible?

One of the commands I'd like to run is `pg_dump`, and the credentials are in a shell file:

Basically I'm trying to run this:

```
bash -c "pg_dump \$PRODUCTION_DB --password \$PRODUCTION_PASSWORD --user \$PRODUCTION_USERNAME --host \$PRODUCTION_HOST > #{backup_name}.sql"
```

Comment: what about passing it as variables? like ``script | command "$X" "$Y"``. If you want to push the changes upstream then you will have to use a file.

Comment: Using them as variables would be just what I need. One of the commands I'm running is pg_dump, and I'm passing it the credentials to the DB.

Comment: Why don't you just return them? ``X=$(command "$X")``. Doing that for two variables might require some parsing but it's not that hard

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the parsing part? I'm not sure I understand completely what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use a pipe. Assuming you have the `export` commands in the first script, those variables will be available to the second script.

```
. ./path/to/script
command_that_has_access_to_X_and_Y
```

---

A pipeline is simply a tool for connecting the standard input of one script to the standard output of another. It's an efficient alternative to using a temporary file; `x | y` is more-or-less the same as

```
x > tmp.txt
y < tmp.txt
```

except the operating systems handles the details of passing text from `x` to `y` so that both can run at the same time, with `y` receiving input as `x` produces it.

Comment: You're so right. I have no clue why I've complicated myself such :D. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could send by echo instead:

Script on the left:

```
#!/bin/bash
X='Something X'
Y='Something Y'
echo "$X"
echo "$Y"
```

Command on the right:

```
... | bash -c "read -r X; read -r Y; echo \"\$X : \$Y\""
```

Produces:

```
Something X : Something Y
```