# How to pass a value to a playwright test?

Tags: bash, npm, playwright, pnpm

I want to create a `pnpm` script that generates test data and runs my test on said data like so:

`"e2e:test1": "bash ./generateTestData.sh && npx playwright test test1.spec.ts"`

my data-gen script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate a new patient
id=$(command to generate new patient here)
echo " Generated new patient"'

guid=$(...some other code to get the right values)

export GUID=$guid
```

As you can see here i want to set the reference to my generated patient in an env variable that i can then use in my playwright test to go to the right URL.

But if i run my commands like so:

`pnpm e2e:test1` the env variable is not set in the playwright test. I also tried to use `source` like so:
`"e2e:test1": "bash -c 'source generateTestData.sh && npx playwright test e2e/test1.spec.ts'"`

that didnt work either.

How can I get the result of my data-generation into my playwright test?

Comment: See [How can I pipe to the next command with new environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684685/how-can-i-pipe-to-the-next-command-with-new-environment-variables). Besides export/source, another option is to write to a file which the test will read, or echo the data into the pipe (although the playwright command might not forward these to the test script--I'd have to experiment with it to see). You could also have the generator script run `npx playwright test` for you as a subprocess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pipe to the next command with new environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684685/how-can-i-pipe-to-the-next-command-with-new-environment-variables)

Comment: Yes I made it work by making the generator script also run the playwright command. But I want to separate the scripts so I generate data without starting tests etc.

I also tried creating a second script that runs the generator then the npx playwright command. The tests dont have access to the exported variables then either:(

    ./generate-data.sh \n
    npx playwright test myTest.spec.ts

Comment: And no, I couldnt make it work using the answers in that question it seems

Comment: Assuming pnpm/npm does something that makes it different